# Почему появляется ошибка при первом запуске React?

Tags: reactjs, babel

Создал приложение через create-react-app

```
npm i create-react-app
```

Создал папку приложения и перешел в нее

```
npm init react-app app
cd app
```

При запуске приложения через npm start появляется несколько ошибок Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'

Как это исправить?
Я пробовал поставить babel и добавлял в корень babel.config.js с кодом

```
  babelrcRoots: [
    ".",
    "static/project-b/*"
  ]
};
```

Это не помогло

Полный код ошибки:

````
Error: [BABEL] /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/src/index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'
Require stack: 
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-babel/dist/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/bundle.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js (While processing: "/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js")
at Generator.next ()
at Generator.next ()
at Generator.next ()
at Generator.next ()
at cachedFunction.next ()
at loadPresetDescriptor.next ()
at recursePresetDescriptors.next ()
at Generator.next ()
at loadFullConfig.next ()
at transform.next ()
at new Promise ()
at Generator.next ()
at new Promise ()
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/src/index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'
Require stack:
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-babel/dist/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/bundle.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js (While processing: "/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js")
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at module.exports (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js:168:9)
at module.exports (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js:19:10)
at async (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:36:33)
at async (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:186:15)
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:13
at Generator.next ()
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:181:21
at Generator.next ()
at Function. (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:21:3)
at Generator.next ()
at step (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:269:25)
at evaluateAsync (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
at Function.errback (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:113:7)
at errback (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:66:18)
at async (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:188:17)
at onFirstPause (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:13)
at Generator.next ()
at cachedFunction (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:52:46)
at cachedFunction.next ()
at loadPresetDescriptor (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:294:43)
at loadPresetDescriptor.next ()
at recursePresetDescriptors (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:77:31)
at recursePresetDescriptors.next ()
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:157:21
at Generator.next ()
at loadFullConfig (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:113:5)
at loadFullConfig.next ()
at transform (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:20:45)
at transform.next ()
at step (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:269:25)
at evaluateAsync (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
at errback (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/gensync/index.js:113:7)
at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.js:46:12)
at transform (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:39:72)
at node:internal/util:360:7
at new Promise ()
at transform (node:internal/util:346:12)
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/transform.js:15:22
at Generator.next ()
at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/transform.js:3:103)
at _next (/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/transform.js:4:194)
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/transform.js:4:364
at new Promise ()
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/transform.js:4:97
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/transform.js:48:17
at /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:130:26

ERROR in [eslint] 
src/index.js
Line 0: Parsing error: [BABEL] /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/src/index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'
Require stack:
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-babel/dist/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/bundle.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js (While processing: "/Users/mkde/projectsNew/ToDo/app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/prod.js") ```
````

Comment: Используй команду `npx create-react-app test`, а потом переходи в папку `test` и запускай приложение `npm start`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка связана с отсутствием модуля @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object. Для ее исправления нужно установить пакет с этим модулем, выполнив команду:
`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object`

После установки пакета необходимо перезапустить приложение.